# How much is a person's greenhouse gas footprint reduced by eating vegetarian?

Tags: vegetarian-diet, environment, global-warming

Animal agriculture has been identified as [playing a large role in climate change](http://www.fao.org/livestock-environment/en/). I am interested in how much of a difference someone can make through diet changes.

**How much is the average North American's greenhouse gas footprint reduced by eating vegetarian? What about vegan?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this article: [The carbon footprint of 5 diets compared - shrinkthatfootprint.com](http://shrinkthatfootprint.com/food-carbon-footprint-diet)

It suggests that the **average person produces 2.5 CO2e** a year while a **vegetarian only produces 1.7 CO2e** a year, and **vegans produce 1.5 CO2e a year**.

Apparently, **18% of global carbon emissions come from livestock**